# Set a Property Value From Database of Properties

Tags: properties, vb6, controls

My database has the formname, control, and control property type value stored.

I would like to have a line of code like this.

```
Forms(i%).Controls(ControlName$)).controlpropertytype$ = NewValue
```

I am currently using a select case structure to handle the various property types. It would be much simpler to have a single statement take care of it.

Comment: You cannot do it in one line.  The Forms collection will only take an Index and not a String like you want.  You can do it in one line with a helper function, though.

Comment: There's this little known VB6/VBA command [CallByName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/callbyname-function). You would still need a (more than one line) function to create the resulting one-liner, though. But it should give you more flexibility than a Select Case construct.

Answer (score 2):

Using a helper function, you can achieve this with one line of code.  Here's an example of setting a TextBox on Form1 to the value 'aaa':

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Test()
   CallByName FindForm("Form1").Controls("Text1"), "Text", VbLet, "aaa"
End Sub

Public Function FindForm(ByVal Name As String) As Form
   Dim f As Form

   For Each f In Forms
      If UCase(f.Name) = UCase(Name) Then
         Set FindForm = f
         Exit Function
      End If
   Next
End Function
```

While this is an interesting exercise, I would not recommend this approach.  It assumes the form and the control can both be found, but if they can't be found this one-liner will crash your app.

Here's [documentation for CallByName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/callbyname-function).